# CustomPostDeployTarget invoking before ApplicationStart(Biztalk Deployment Framework)

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2016, biztalk-deployment, btdf

As per BizTalk Deployment Framework :
**CustomPostDeployTarget**
Runs just after the Deployment Framework has deployed all artefacts and started the BizTalk application and just before the BizTalk hosts are restarted.

So in order to unenlist some send ports after 'StartApplication' I have added this target which execute a Powershell Script and working fine.

But why does VStudio execute target before starting the application?

```
Task:
<Target Name="CustomPostDeployTarget">
     <Exec Command="powershell.exe -NoExit -Command &quot;. '&quot;D:\Users\Test\UnenlistSendPorts.ps1&quot;'; UnenlistSendPort_u &quot;&quot;$(ProjectName)&quot; &quot;$(s)&quot;&quot;&quot; "/>     
</Target>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want your command to run after the application is started, use CustomFinalDeploy instead of CustomPostDeployTarget.